# Is it true that it's not possible to draw the similar shape of an arbitary shape

Tags: geometry

Given a polygon of N vertices, you need only N steps to draw the similar shape of any ratio.

I would like to confirm that given a 2D shape which is non-polygonal and not circumscribed by a circle, let's say, the contour of a patato, it's impossible to precisely (in mathematical/ geometrical terms) draw its similar shape (of scaled size)? My argument is that doing so will require infinite number of steps. Such method as approximation/interpolation is not considered to be mathematically/geometrically precise.

If the above assumption is wrong, what is the method to draw such a scaled shape?

Comment: Any geometrical shape can be arbitrarily scaled, of course. `not considered as mathematical/geometrical` What do you consider to be "*mathematical/geometrical*"?

Comment: By mathematical/geometrical, I mean precision

Comment: I can't even precisely draw a circle. Do you mean "with a straightedge and compass"?

Comment: `I mean precision` Define "*precision*". Math-wise, once you know a "*shape*" you know it for good, and there is no question of precision or approximation involved. If you do *not* mean it math-wise, then please clarify *what* you mean, and what kind of answer you are looking for on a *math* oriented board.

Comment: By using a compass, you essentially say each point is of the distance from the center. That's is a math language guarantee precision.

Comment: For example, given a contour of a patato, how to draw its similar shape of half size?

Comment: ...pick a center $O$, and for every point $P$ on the potato, draw the midpoint of the segment $OP$?

Comment: The hard part is where is the midpoint of a irregular shape like patato?   ;-)

Comment: @techie11 `given a contour of a patato, how to draw its similar shape of half size` Overlay a grid, double the unit size of the grid, then zoom in by 2x ;-)  Of course, you'll have to deal with taking the midpoints of an uncountably infinite number of segments, but you'd have all the necessary data if you really "knew" the contour of the potato in the math sense to begin with. If that's not the case, it would help if you spelled out what you *really* know and what exactly you are after.

Comment: You can pick any point $O$, it doesn't have to be the "midpoint" whatever that might mean for a potato.

Comment: Using a grid is a 'engineering' method. But I guess you got the point. If the shape can be decomposed to countable number of shapes for which midpoints can be found, then the task can be done, otherwise it's impossible.

Comment: @techie11 Sorry, but I am afraid that you missed the point. Countable or not does not matter here (as long as we are talking about reasonably smooth curves). But you *still* did not define `the task` in math terms.

Comment: @Rahul choosing any point that are not the midpoint of the shape will distort the shape, hence they will not be not similar. For example, pick midpoint of the radius of a circle and scale every point by half, the result is not a circle.

Comment: @dxiv you are probably right. The task is to draw a similar shape by scale ratio.

Comment: @techie11 `For example, pick midpoint of the radius of a circle and scale every point by half, the result is not a circle` But it *is* a circle, just try it (or lookup [homotheties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homothetic_transformation)).

Comment: @Rahul,@dxiv thank you!

Comment: @Misha Lavrov first thank you should go to you :-)

Comment: @dxiv: looks like homothety is the theory behind both the vector fonts and perspective drawing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us take the leaf of a tree whose contour may not admit mathematical definition.(ie irregular)  One can paste that leaf on a transparent sheet and pass light through that sheet  and  capture the image  (shadow) on a screen at a distance suitably calculated to produce magnification at a desired level. (Of course ensure that light falls perpendicularly onto the sheet and that the screen and the sheet are parallel).

Comment: this is the "homothety" (mentioned by dxiv) in action.

Comment: @techie11: I am not original. I simply made things explicit (in this case a physical process) avoiding technical terms.